# Google Cloud Storage web hosting: redirect http to https

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, devops, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm hosting a static website on a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The bucket is named as my domain:
`www.example.com`.

I also have a single Cloud Load Balancer forwarding rule on GCP with my bucket configured as its backend.
I'd like to configure my load balancer so that each request to HTTP protocol is redirected to HTTPS.

What is the simplest method to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) will help you to setting up redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. Are you looking for this?

Comment: The comment is the answer!

Comment: Actually this is not the case. As this suggested URL talks about backend service, my website is hosted on GCE bucket, therefore this document above is not relevant for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hosting website on a bucket can be done by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#gsutil). On the same page it's mentioned that if you want to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS then you need to set up additional HTTP-LB with a redirected setting in the URL map. Here is the step by step process to setting up [redirection from HTTP to HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect).